# are there problems with this macro - check status and return if failed

Tags: c++, macros, error-handling

we have a frequently recurring lines in the code that check for the return status of a function, and if it's a failure return with the status immediately. I thought of defining a macro for this:

```
#define RETURN_IF_FAILED(x) { int stat = (x); if (FAILED(stat)) return stat; }
```

The local variable is because the parameter `x` could be a function call.

As I know there are some weird artifacts of using macros and I am not very proficient in them, I'd like to ask if you see any problems with this macro. Thanks.

(and please, don't suggest to use exceptions - I hate this style myself, but that's the way it's done here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to modify it a bit; enclosing it with `do{} while(0)` like this:

```
#define RETURN_IF_FAILED(x) do { int stat = (x); if (FAILED(stat)) return stat; } while(0)
```

Now you can use this MACRO, like this:

```
if (SomeCondition)
  RETURN_IF_FAILED(x); //<--- note the "usual" semicolon!
else
{
   //some code
}
```

With your version, this code is NOT possible at all. The `;` after the macro would cause problem in your version!

Comment: @davka : Exactly. `;` is the problem!

Comment: Why `do{` and `}while(0)`? Wouldn`t `{` and `}` be enough?

Comment: @peoro : the `;` would cause problem. Try expanding the original macro in the code snippet I given. You will immediately see this!

Comment: @peoro: no, because `if { ... }; else ...` will generate a compile error.

Comment: Ouch! I missed the whole point of your answer then... Should read answers twice before commenting...