# C++ code generation for repeated task

Tags: c++

I have something like below which will get repeated many times based on the function 
 that get called

for e.g

```
  acceptfunction()
  {
       inserter["quantity"] = sdd.getfloat(quantity);
       inserter["prodtype"]  = sdd.getstring(prodtype);
         :
         :
       so on 
   }
```

Like accept above there are 20 more functions(reject,cancel etc) which will do the
  similar thing.But the parameteres they insert can differ based on function called.

How can I automate this kind of code.So that I dont need to write new function from
  scratch.Basically what I need is if i provide parametres like ("quantity",prodtype)
  through some text file or xml, it should generate the required function with the 
  input parametres.

Is this task can be handled through C++ tempalte Meta programming or someother code
  generation tool will help me to do this?

Comment: what are `quantity` and `prodtype` in the functions `getfloat()` and `getstring()`. are they of same type?

Comment: Too vague...  But since you're using Tools.h++...  There's probably a solution already built in that does what you want.  Read the docs harder. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but you can use a preprocessor macro:

```
#define FUNCTION_MACRO(NAME, ATTRIB1, ATTRIB2)\
void NAME()\
{\
    inserter[#ATTRIB1] = sdd.getfloat(ATTRIB1);\
    inserter[#ATTRIB2]  = sdd.getstring(ATTRIB2);\
}
```

And then to create a function you just need to do:

```
FUNCTION_MACRO(accept_function, quantity, prodtype)
```

Comment: How about using `#ATTRIB1` instead of `"ATTRIB1"` in `inserter`? Anyway good attempt. +1

Comment: Macro are the only things in c/c++ which can convert an identifier into string  .. so this is a good way

Comment: The macro above will be helpful only if all the functions has fixed number of attributes.It's not the case here.Based on kind of function, number of attributes differ. It can be 10 or 20 or 30. Apart from this passing all those many parametres is cumbersome.

Comment: Hi Nawaz,quantity and prodtype

Comment: @sateesh : you can write N number of such macros. and choose from them when you need one. You can even write small macros to be called from (better would be to say, to be written in) such macros if that makes your life easy!

Comment: This offers a way to define different functions similar to `acceptFunction`, but I think the question is asking how to parameterize the repeated lines within `acceptFunction`.

Comment: @sateesh, I don't much like this solution either.  I tried to think of something using C++0x variadic templates, but ultimately the problem is the string literals.  As Vardhan Varma said, converting an identifier into a string literal is only possible through the preprocessor as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Nawaz, quantity and prodtype are of fix tag types.

Comment: @sateesh : *tag types* means? Are they string? Or enum or what?

Comment: @Jon Reid, no the OP said there are other functions like reject and cancel.

Comment: @Downvoter : Why downvote? Is it not a good attempt given that the question is so vague?

Comment: Nawaz, they are string type as below, const RWCString FixTag::CLIENT_APP_NAME              = "2025";

Comment: @Charles: My bad, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when it comes down do it, you almost certainly could but it would require implementing an XML or text parser in TMP.  Would be quite a feat.

That's not how things would normally be done, but you've not specified enough details to go into it further.

Comment: Apolosize if the question is so confusing.Just to gove some more info on the question , inserter that appear in the code is nothing but RWTValVector.sdd that appear in my code is hash map.Application retrives the value from the hashmap(sdd) by using tag (strings) and insert it into inserter which is vector from roguewave.Later this vectro is used to insert data into databse table. So the acutal code appears as inserter["quantity"] << sdd.getfloat(fixtag::quantity); Here fixtag::quantity is a string asbelow fixtag::quantity "2050".

Answer (score 0):

Macros are generally to be avoided, but this is a case where they are still useful. Something like

```
#define GET_FUNCTION(type, name)                    \
    do                                              \
    {                                               \
        inserter[#name] = sdd.get ## type(name);    \
    }                                               \
    while (0)
```

will let you say

```
void acceptfunction()
{
    GET_FUNCTION(float, quantity);
    GET_FUNCTION(string, prodtype);
    // etc...
}
```

(The reason for the odd do-while construct is to guarantee that the result is a single statement.)

Define different macros for rejectfunction(), etc.

Comment: +1 for so-called `do-while` construct. similar thing here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615171/are-there-problems-with-this-macro-check-status-and-return-if-failed

Comment: Apolosize if the question is so confusing.Just to gove some more info on the question , inserter that appear in the code is nothing but RWTValVector.sdd that appear in my code is hash map.Application retrives the value from the hashmap(sdd) by using tag (strings) and insert it into inserter which is vector from  roguewave.Later this vectro is used to insert data into databse table.  So the acutal code appears as inserter["quantity"] << sdd.getfloat(fixtag::quantity); Here fixtag::quantity is a string asbelow fixtag::quantity "2050"

Comment: So all it does here is read values from hashmap and insert them into vector for later processing. For  accept function application may need 10 attributes, for reject function application may need 20 attributes to fill. Thats the reason I asked can i put some meta data in some text file and use it as input to generate code